# Ionic Peer to Peer

Tags: ionic-framework, p2p

Does Ionic support peer to peer on both Android and iOS platforms?  Looking for hybrid or plugin support for iOS Mulitipeer Connectivity and Android WiFi Direct.  Not interested in Bluetooth.  Too slow for my application.

Comment: Did you find anything looking into?

Comment: No, thus far interoperable Multipeer connectivity between iOS and Android does not seem to exist.  Both use very different networking protocols that are incompatible.  A couple of groups -- Thali, Alljoyn --  are trying to come up with a solution but I have not heard of any success.  The only successful interoperable platforms use Bluetooth.  I have heard complaints that Bluetooth is way too slow for this implementation.  How about you?  Have you heard anything different?

Comment: I only found stuff about Alljoyn. Found a Cordova Alljoyn plugin as well but it only works for android.

Comment: Check this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-networking-multipeer) , might be helpful!